Better term for a stop on the route?
I am working on a software project and have a problem to find a name for entity that holds location (address, longitude, latitude etc) and time range (from time, to time).
The location entity is called 'Location'.
So far I called it 'Point' but I don't like this name because IMHO it is not self-descriptive.
So, the entity I have to define looks like:
Point
    location: Location
    from: Date
    to: Date


(the word after semicolon indicates the field type, e.g. 'Location', 'Date')
Can you guys, suggest a better name instead of 'Point' (or confirm that my choice is good enough)?

Stops along a route are commonly referred to as waypoints.

@KillingTime I have already renamed it to RouteStop but I like WayPoint more, so I will rename.

The time spent at a "waypoint" (if it's an actual intermediate stopping point, rather than just a "route timing" point) is often referred to as layover.

Entity names are off-topic: you could name it Susan and it would work just as well. Have a look at another question and see if yours can be altered in the same vein.

stopover From M-W: A stopover is a stop at an intermediate point in one's journey or a stopping place on a journey.

Since the entity involves both place and time you could call it a stay. The noun stay is commonly used in a travel context, especially in regard to overnight accommodations.

How was your stay?

If your software is tracking deliveries, it's not a good suggestion, but if its context is travel and tourism, stay is idiomatic.

wow, stay! How I did not think about it myself? Thanks a lot!
